# Unable to queue a build with shelve - TFS

Tags: build, shelve, shelveset, unshelve

I has customize the DefaultTemplate and change the SyncWorkspace activity to TfGet activity.
Now I'm trying to queue a build with shelve but the build seem to ignore the shelve and ran the build without the shelve, I'v tried to queue the same build with the same shelve in the default template and everything is fine..
There is anyone that know what the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have to use TF get activity to get the sources. There are some obvious differences between the both SyncWorkspace and Tf get activity. Recommend you to use TF get source activity. Tess pass on my environment with below settings.

[image]

Comment: Test pass with my local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Each build process template has a parameter called **SupportedReasons**. This enum is normally set to all. Make sure you have this parameter in your customized templated and didn't change the value.
[image]

Comment: I checked that.. I have this property and the value is 'all'

Comment: in the build report I can see the 'Validate Shelveset' in the title but when the build get to the TfGet activity he ignore the shelve.